# Google Images heterogeneous Thumb Positioning

Tags: html, layout, user-interface, canvas

Google Image Search returns Images of different sizes. even their Thumbs are of different size. But still they are arranged in such a way that keeps a clean margin. even resizing the browser keeps the left and right alignment proper. What I've noticed is they group a Page of Image into an ul and each image is in an li. not all rows contain same amount of images. But still how they manage to keep images of different sizes properly aligned ?

EDIT

Though I've accepted an answer Its not exact match. It may be a near match. However I still want to know What is the exact procedure they are doing. I cannot chalk out the pattern. 
It seems that they wrap a `page` in a `<ol>` and put images in `<li>` But when I resize the images are redistributed among pages. But how many images the `page <ol>` should contain now is to be decided. What procedure can be used to accomplish that ? and also images are resized based on a `standard` height I think. and that standard height is changed on resize. How how much ? how that is decided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the same thing, but you might get some useful ideas about how to optimize image "packing" by looking at the approach taken by the [jQuery Masonry plug-in](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/).

Comment: +1 Nice alternative. However I still want to know (how) the Google way.

Comment: If you use Firebug, you can see that they're doing a bunch of interesting things: using `<canvas>` to (apparently) dynamically crop the thumbnails to achieve a desired spacing, encoding base64 image data directly into the JS, etc. Since they're both cropping and resizing in JavaScript, it's not hard to imagine how they can coerce elements of each row to a desired width and spacing.

Answer (score 0):

They know how big each thumbnail is, since it's stored in their image database. They just make each `<li>` float left, and make them a fixed size based on whatever the largest image is within that section of images.

Comment: all Thumbs are of fixed size. and thumbs are not generated based on browser size or screen resolution.  so is it that simple ? I still doubt there must be some tricky measurements done on the margin and padding to make distances between smaller images.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if someone at Google's solved the Knapsack problem, or at least come up with a handy method to reduce the complexity of it. You'll notice that if you do end up with various width/thumbnails, parts of the image get lopped off, so it's not too hard to figure out a minimum number of images in a row and adjust the size of the li to get proper spacing.

Comment: Yaah Its true that this thing is not too hard. and it is really simple and easy. But its such a thing, If someone asks I can somehow make them understand non-mathematically but how exact its going on is kind of easy confusing puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little plugin just to do that **[HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waRWMJ)** you can watch it in action:

```
(function($){
//to arrange elements like google image
//start of the plugin
var tm=TweenMax;
  var positionFunc= function(options, elem){
        var setting=$.extend({
            height:150,
            container:$('body'),
            margin:5,
            borderWidth:1,
            borderColor:'#000',
            borderStyle:'solid',
            boxShadow:'0 0 0 #000',
            borderRadius:0,
            type:'img'
            },options);
        tm.set($(elem),{
            'max-height':setting.height
            });
        $(elem).wrap('<div class="easyPositionWrap"></div>');
        var winsize=setting.container.width();
        var thisrow=0;
        var elementsused=0;
        var row=0;
        tm.set($('.easyPositionWrap'),{
            border:setting.borderWidth+'px '+setting.borderStyle+' '+setting.borderColor,
            borderRadius:setting.borderRadius,
            boxShadow:setting.boxShadow,
            margin:setting.margin,
            height:setting.height,
            position:'relative',
            display:'block',
            overflow:'hidden',
            float:'left'
            });
        $('.easyPositionWrap').each(function(index, element) {
            if(thisrow<winsize){
                thisrow+=$(this).width()+(setting.margin*2)+(setting.borderWidth*2);
                }
            else{
                var currentwidth=thisrow-$(this).prevUntil('.easyPositionWrap:eq('+(elementsused-1)+')').width()-(setting.margin*2)+(setting.borderWidth*2);
                var nextimagewidth=$(this).prev('.easyPositionWrap').width()+(setting.margin*2)+(setting.borderWidth*2);
                var elems=$(this).prevAll('.easyPositionWrap').length-elementsused;
                var widthtobetaken=(nextimagewidth-(winsize-currentwidth))/(elems);
                if(widthtobetaken!=0){
                    if(elementsused==0){
                        $(this).prevUntil('.easyPositionWrap:eq(0)').each(function(index, element) {
                            $(this).width($(this).width()-widthtobetaken);
                            $(this).find(setting.type+':first-child').css('margin-left','-'+(widthtobetaken/2)+'px');
                            });
                        $('.easyPositionWrap:eq(0)').width($('.easyPositionWrap:eq(0)').width()-widthtobetaken);
                        $('.easyPositionWrap:eq(0) '+setting.type).css('margin-left','-'+(widthtobetaken/2)+'px');
                        }
                    else{
                        $(this).prevUntil('.easyPositionWrap:eq('+(elementsused-1)+')').each(function(index, element) {
                            $(this).width($(this).width()-widthtobetaken);
                            $(this).find(setting.type+':first-child').css('margin-left','-'+(widthtobetaken/2)+'px');
                            });
                        }
                    }
                elementsused+=elems;
                thisrow=$(this).width()+(setting.margin*2)+(setting.borderWidth*2);
                }
            });
        $(window).resize(function(){
            clearTimeout(window.thePositionTO);
            window.thePositionTO=setTimeout(function(){
                $(elem).each(function(index, element) {
                    $(this).unwrap('.easyPositionWrap');
                    $(this).data('easyPositioned',false);
                    });
                $(elem).easyPosition(options);
                },200);
            });
        }
    $.fn.easyPosition= function(options){
        if($(this).data('easyPositioned')) return;
        positionFunc(options, this);
        $(this).data('easyPositioned',true);
        };
//end of the plugin
    }(jQuery));

$(window).load(function(){
    $('img').easyPosition();
});
```

**libraries to include:**

- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)
- [GreenSock's TweenMax](http://greensock.com/)